# better query to get user monthly rank?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: 
user_score_post -> fields: id, post_id, user_id, score_date -> with about 3m rows
post -> field: id, user_id, body -> with about 10k rows...

and this is my query for retrieving monthly rank of a user with dedicated user_id and score according to the number of likes that his posts have:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(l.id) AS likes
        FROM user_score_post l
        JOIN post p ON p.id = l.post_id
        AND score_date >= :time // last month
        GROUP BY p.user_id) AS score
    WHERE score.likes > :score // user current score
```

but it takes 2.4 seconds to execute. Is it normal despite using proper indexes and a powerful dedicated server? 
what is the best alternative for this query? and what is the best indexing composition?

Comment: is id unique to a post? if so then  not sure why you have it in user_score_post as well. It is redundant there. Doesn't answer the question, but your answer will help to clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in MySQL it is faster to use a correlated subquery rather than a join with aggregation.  You might try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS likes
              FROM user_score_post l
              WHERE p.id = l.post_id AND score_date >= :time
             ) as likes
      FROM post p
     ) score
WHERE score.likes > :score // user current score
```

Then, the index that you want is `user_score_post(post_id, score_date)`.  This might help.

Comment: Thank you but the last line is not true. we cannot use score.likes here! double check it please.

Comment: because you are defining the likes in the inner select. I tested your query and it says that there is a syntax error

Comment: @salehhashemi . . . I see.  I confused myself.  The `as likes` needs to be one level further out . . . or the column has no name.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the following returns the score for each user.  Perhaps also score_date should use bewteen month start and end.

```
select p.user_id, count(*) from user_post_score l 
join post p on (p.user_id=l.user_id)
where score_date  > :time 
group by p.user_id
```